# winrt trouble with std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime

I cloned https://github.com/kennykerr/cppwinrt, and added the two lines @line 70 (after including the filesystem header):

```
if (!std::experimental::filesystem::exists(winrt::to_string(file.Path())))
    exit(12345);
```

And it exits with 12345. Always. Why? I thought winrt was supposed to work with standard iso c++? Even if I hardcode a filename instead of the "to_string(data_file)", it still dies.

If it has something to do with UWP running in a sandbox, that's fine, but why isn't the filepicker working?

This is more or less the easiest example I can pull up. For some reason, no matter what I try, I cannot operate on files.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you missed the important fact that each winrt application runs in own sandbox. Each file path you try to access is relatively to application sandbox root, although a given path is absolute, it is absolute in sandbox and the system interprets it as relative path to sandbox root. To get access to files outside sandbox you should apply more efforts, declare a path with required files shared between sandboxes or place a file into already available system shared directories. In this case a path will not be absolute again, it will be accessed relative to shared path.